# Azure Monitor for Active Directory monitoring

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I want to monitor their on-premise AD infrastructure with Azure Monitor and want to monitor and generate reports on these metrics
a.  Details of disabled users currently in in AD
b.  Users with password not required
c.  Users with password never expiry
d.  Users with “Kerberos pre-authentication disabled”
e.  Users not logged on for last 90 days
f.  Stale computers/Computers inactive for last 90 days
g.  Objects trusted to authenticate for delegation
h.  Uptime of AD infra (average uptime of all domain controllers)
Does Active Directory health check solution on Log Analytics  meets all these expectations?

Comment: You can use Azure AD Connect Health to monitor on-premise AD. For more details, please refer to  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/03/16/step-by-step-monitoring-on-premise-active-directory-via-azure-ad-connect-health/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the [AD Health check solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/ad-assessment) (which is more of an AD assessment) can help with all of your above tasks.

From what I know, this solution consists of "several health check assessments which run on regular intervals in domain controllers to identify issues and risks and provide recommendations to improve the existing infrastructure up to Microsoft best practices.", as described in [this community article](https://www.terminalworks.com/blog/post/2018/08/26/monitoring-active-directory-using-operational-management-suit-oms).

**Possible solution:**

If you know where to get all this information from Event Viewer or other log file on the system, you can use the Azure Monitoring Agent or the Log Analytics agent (MMA) to monitor specific events or specific log records/lines from various custom logs on the server.

AMA Agent = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-overview?tabs=PowerShellWindows

Data collection for specific events = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-collection-rule-azure-monitor-agent

If you prefer the classic MMA agent (which will be replaced by the AMA agent above in about 2 years), you can look here:

MMA Agent = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/log-analytics-agent

Custom Log collection = https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs